# WP nav menu + Bootstrap, add role="menu" to UL

Tags: menus, twitter-bootstrap

For one of my projects I'm trying to add a nav_menu to my WP theme. It should work as a quick menu (sidebar). The only problem remaining: How do I add a **role="menu"** to the **< ul >**?

```
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'menu',
            'theme_location'    => 'menu',
            'depth'             => 0,
            'container'         => '',
            'menu_class'        => 'dropdown-menu',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
```

I'm looking for the output `<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">` anyone ?

Comment: We highly encourage users to answer their own questions. You can accept it as solution two days later. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Update]** Solution found:

I was looking for `'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" role="menu" >%3$s</ul>'`

```
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'menu',
            'theme_location'    => 'menu',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" role="menu" >%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'             => 0,
            'container'         => '',
            'menu_class'        => 'dropdown-menu',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
```